# Android App Crashes With ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android

I am trying to set up my Navigation Drawer listener for my MainScreen activity. When I set everything up, my app crashes when I try use ActionBarDrawerToggle. Are there other ways of implementing this?

> Unable to start activity `ComponentInfo{koeksworld.com.firstandroidproject/koeksworld.com.firstandroidproject.UserMainPanel}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener)' on a null object reference`

Here is some of the code in my activity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_main_panel);
    listener = new NavigationDrawerItemListener(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.groceryAppHomeToolbar);
    homeDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainDrawerLayout);
    homeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.homeListView);
    homeListView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlue));
    navigationArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigationArray);
    navigationAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            navigationArray);
    homeListView.setAdapter(navigationAdapter);
    homeListView.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
    //The suspected culprit
    drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, homeDrawer, toolbar, R
            .string
            .open_drawer, R
            .string.close_Drawer);
    homeDrawer.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
    drawerListener.syncState();
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}
```

Comment: can u please share your layout file, this kind of problems are mainly arrived bcz of XML file controls placing structure.

Comment: homeDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainDrawerLayout); Are you sure you have a R.id.mainDrawerLayout in R.layout.activity_user_main_panel?

Comment: Go into your XML and make sure that the layout has the id name "mainDrawerLayout", then check that you're setting the right layout. Basically, that's probably your error.

Comment: I feel so silly right now... I went and double checked that line, and it appears I was linking to another DrawerLayout on another XML file :( I fixed that up and now it works.

Comment: did u see my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the same id for the **navigation drawer** in `findViewById(R.id.mainDrawerLayout)` and in the layout file.

Seems `mDrawerLayout` is null when calling `.setDrawerListener()`